# how to solve this error in laravel: ErrorException (E_WARNING) Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: laravel

I am creating a medicine shop invoice system . So at that process, I am creating a invoice form where customer information and invoicing information store in a two different model Customer model and Invoice model.

My invoice form view code below;

```
<form action="{{url('/invoice')}}" method="post">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
        <label for="customerName">Customer Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName" class="form-control"><br>

        <label for="address"> Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="form-control"><br>

        <label for="mobile"> Mobile No.:</label>
        <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobileNumber" class="form-control"><br>



    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="invoiceNo"> Invoice No.:</label>
        <input type="text" id="invoiceNo" name="invoiceNum" class="form-control"><br>

        <label for="date"> Date:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date" class="form-control"><br>

    </div>

</div>
<hr>
<table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="5px">
    <thead>
    <th>Meidicine Name:.</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Total Price</th>
    <th style="text-align: center"><a href="#" class="addRow"><i class="fas fa-plus-square plus "></i></a></th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>

        <td>

            <select name="medicineName" id="" class="form-control-sm medicineName" >
                @foreach($data as $item)
                <option value="{{$item->id}}">{{$item->medicineName}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control-sm quantity" name="quantity"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control-sm price" name="price"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control-sm totalAmount" name="totalAmount"></td>
        <td style="text-align: center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></td>

    </tr>

    <tr><td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="ADD"></td></tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
</form>
```

In this invoice form medicine name came from another model Medicine using laravel eloquent relationship

my InvoiceController store method code below

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $customer = new Customer();

    $customer->fill($request->all());
    if($customer->save()){

        $id = $customer->id;
        foreach($request->medicineName as $value => $key)  --->error occurs 
                                                                this line
            {

            $data = array(
                'customer_id' => $id,
                'medicine_id' => $value,
                'invoiceNum' => $request->invoiceNum[$key],
                'date'       =>$request->date[$key],
                'quantity'   =>$request->quantity[$key],
                'price'      =>$request->price[$key],
                'totalAmount'=> $request->totalAmount[$key]
            );
        Invoice::insert($data);

        }
    }

    return back();

}
```

when I click ADD button to submit data two different model Customer & Invoice browser can show error look like
"ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

How to solve this type of error, pls anyone can help me..

Comment: You have used select that will select only one value not multiple. What are you trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because `$request->medicineName` is just one element and not an array or collection, try it like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $customer = new Customer();

    $customer->fill($request->all());
    if($customer->save()){

        $id = $customer->id;

        $data = array(
            'customer_id' => $id,
            'medicine_id' => $request->medicineName,
            'invoiceNum' => $request->invoiceNum,
            'date'       =>$request->date,
            'quantity'   =>$request->quantity,
            'price'      =>$request->price,
            'totalAmount'=> $request->totalAmount
        );
        Invoice::insert($data);
    }

    return back();

}
```

Comment: Your answer is right and data is stored properly. Many many thanks for your helping